# Handling mysql queries in php mvc

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm working on an application written in PHP. I decided to follow the MVC architecture.
However, as the code gets bigger and bigger, I realized that some code gets duplicated in some cases. Also, I'm still confused whether I should use static functions when quering the database or not.

Let's take an example on how I do it :

```
class User {
  private id;
  private name;
  private age;
}
```

Now, inside this class I will write methods that operate on a single user instance (CRUD operations). On the other hand, I added general static functions to deal with multiple users like :

```
public static function getUsers()
```

The main problem that I'm facing is that I have to access fields through the results when I need to loop through users in my views. for example :

```
$users = User::getUsers();
// View
foreach($users as $user) {
  echo $user['firstname'];
  echo $user['lastname'];
}
```

I decided to do this because I didn't feel it's necessary to create a single user instance for all the users just to do some simple data processing like displaying their informations. But, what if I change the table fields names ? I have to go through all the code and change those fields, and this is what bothers me.

So my question is, how do you deal with database queries like that, and is it fine to use static functions when querying the database. And finally, where is it logical to store those "displaying" functions like the one I talked about ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems fine, howerver I would still use caching like `memcached` to cache values and then you can remove static.

```
public function getUsers() {
   $users = $cacheObj->get('all_users');
   if ($users === false) {
     //use your query to grab users and set it to cache
     $users = "FROM QUERY";

     $cacheObj->set('all_users', $users);
   }

   return $users;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the $cacheObj->get('all_users') works ? Or can you suggest an article that treats this caching method ?

Answer (score -1):

**(M)odel (V)iew (C)ontroller** is a great choice choice, but my advice is look at using a framework. The con is they can have a step learning curve, pro is it does a lot of heavy lifting. But if you want to proceed on your own fair play, it can be tough to do it yourself.

Location wise you have a choice because the model is not clearly define:
You'll hear the term "business logic" used, basically **Model** has everything baring views and the controllers. The controllers should be lean only moving data then returning it to the view.

You model houses DB interaction, data conversions, timezone changes, general day to day functions.

Moudle
    /User
     /Model
      /DB or (Entities and Mapper)
      /Utils

I use Zend and it uses table gateways for standard CRUD to avoid repetition.

Where you have the getUsers() method you just pass a array to it, and it becomes really reusable and you'd just have different arrays in various controller actions and it builds the queries for you from the array info.

Example:

```
$data = array ('id' => 26) 
$userMapper->getUsers($data);
```

to get user 26

```
enter code here
$data = array ('active' => 1, 'name' => 'Darren') 
$userMapper->getUsers($data);`
```

to get active users named Darren

I hope this help.